# Metric non-invariant under permutation of the coordinates

Tags: metric-spaces

I need to prove that in $\mathbb C^2$ the function $d:\mathbb C^2 × \mathbb C^2 → [0, \infty)$ defined by

$$d(x,y)=|x_1 −y_1|+|x_1 −y_1 −x_2 +y_2|$$

is a metric that is not invariant under permutation of the coordinates.

I have tried to give a counterexample, for example:

Let $x$, $y$ $\in \mathbb C^2$ then compute their distance $d(x,y)$, after that permutate the coordinates of the vectors, getting $x'$, $y'$ and recalculate the distance $d(x',y')$, but the distances that I obtained are the same (which I don't want, I need them to be different).

Comment: Use `$\to$` for $\to$.

Comment: $x_1 = y_1 = y_2 = 0, x_2 = 1$ seems to be a counterexample ? or have I misunderstood something ?

Comment: Yes it is correct. I thought I had already used those points, but apparently I overlooked them. Thank you @Imsteffan